# What word would I use for things that are bad for you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

I need a single or double word for a category name for my blog that means: Things that are bad for you, such as smoking, drinking, etc. when you have diabetes. The word must be for all things that can be bad for you.

Comment: does this refer to things that are bad for you ONLY when you have diabetes?

Comment: How about "Cons", as in "Pros and Cons"?

Comment: #1 Diabetes Kryptonite #2 Diabetes No-no's Others: Buzz-killers, Showstoppers, Epic Fails, Diabetes BSOD's (Windows geeky)

Answer (score 4):

In disease management, there is often a discussion of *[risk factors](http://ndep.nih.gov/am-i-at-risk/DiabetesRiskFactors.aspx)*.  While risk factors  include the negative activities you enumerate, they also include circumstances that are beyond your control, such as age, family history, ethnicity etc.

Perhaps the phrase **threat factors** may be more suitable to your purpose.  The word *[threat](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/threat)* means

> a. an indication of imminent danger, harm, evil, etc.
>
> b. a potential source of this

The items you list are more direct threats (and things that can be avoided) than are the broader category of *risks*.

Comment: I'm a physician, and we would use the term "modifiable risk factors" to describe these things are deleterious to the health of a diabetic.

Answer (score 3):

A typical way of describing this would be *vices* or *weaknesses*.

If it's particularly exceptional or specific, maybe call it an *Achilles' heel*.

But vice I think is the best fit here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice

> Vice is a practice, behavior, or habit generally considered immoral,
>   depraved, or degrading in the associated society. In more minor usage,
>   vice can refer to a fault, a negative character trait, a defect, an
>   infirmity, or a bad or unhealthy habit (such as an addiction to
>   smoking). Synonyms for vice include fault, depravity, sin, iniquity,
>   wickedness, and corruption.

Answer (score 3):

Another word to use as in bad for you health-wise could be opposite of beneficial which is detrimental.

Comment: Or, as a blog category for the OP: "Detriments"

Answer (score 1):

If you're just talking about things that pose health risks (that are "bad for you" as in "bad for your body"), I'd say *unhealthy* is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A rather informal answer comes to mind: A female friend with a particular and dangerous allergy once stated to me "Nuts are my enemy!" - this can be adapted in two quite different ways:

I am diabetic and too much sugary food is my enemy.

Diabetes is my enemy, which I can keep in check with an appropriate diet.

Answer (score 0):

Deleterious

All of these items are deleterious to the health of a diabetic.